# ios: turn on/off airplane mode from code for iPhone / iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Activate airplane mode programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793924/activate-airplane-mode-programatically)

is there a way to turn on/off airplane mode in ios (>4.x) from code?
I am looking for some (offical) API calls...

Greetings,
Marco

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible without using private API.

Comment: Does this mean, that if i use private API calls the app will be 100% rejected by apple?

Comment: As opposed to half rejected :)

Comment: Can you tell me which private API is used for that..., just want to learn about it