# iOS can I switch airplane mode?

Tags: ios, swift

I wanna know, can I turn on/off airplane mode on iPhone with swift?
If yes, how to do that?

I'm interesting about iOS 9.0 and latter.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible (at least not if you want you app not to be rejected), see [the following Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793924/activate-airplane-mode-programmatically) as well as [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075797/ios-turn-on-off-airplane-mode-from-code-for-iphone-ipad).

Comment: There is still no public API for this.

Comment: I need it just for me, It's private app, can anybody help with that? I need to be able to done just 2 functions - turn on and off