# Handle airplane mode on/off status from iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, airplane-mode

Is there any way to handle airplane mode on/off from iOS app? If yes then please let me know how to handle it.

Comment: No, it's not See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469425/toggling-airplane-mode-in-ios-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your `Info.plist` file -

[image]

To test this-

1. Kill your app
2. Turn your phone's airplane mode and then
3. Open your app.

You will see an alert when app start.
Thank you.

Comment: Can I make the dialog appear in a specific ViewController(not the launcher one)?