# How to activate airplane mode of Iphone 8 plus with ios 11.0.2 on/off programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, airplane-mode, libimobiledevice

Below is my goal
- I want test something which REQUIRES to restart the phone or activate the airplane mode ON/OFF using any program.

Current Setup:
- I am having IPhone 8Plus with IOS version 11.0.2(15A421)
- Windows 10 with 64 bit OS

Already tried:
I downloaded the " libimobiledevice-1.2.1.202-windows-x86.zip " from the link 
" https://ci.appveyor.com/project/qmfrederik/libimobiledevice/branch/msvc-master/artifacts ".
But when I run idevice_id.exe it gives me VCRUNTIME140.dll error and asking me to reinstall.

Moreover, there is no single setup file which will help me to install the program so I am not sure if I am making any mistake. And also, do I need to connect my IPhone with the laptop where I am setting this application?

Regards
Omer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toggling AirPlane mode in iOS Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469425/toggling-airplane-mode-in-ios-programmatically)

Comment: The question title indicates you want to do it programmatically, but the body of the question indicates you are just trying to install a program, not write any code. Non-programming related questions are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on Stack Overflow. If this *is* programming related, then edit your question to include the code you have tried.

Comment: Hi, title gives the ultimate goal but body is giving the currently where I am now. So to clarify, I will do the coding part after I can install it. So any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I understand you are trying to run `idevice_id` which ships with the 32-bit (x86) version `libimobiledevice-win32` of libimobiledevice, but you get an error message indicating that `vcruntime140.dll` is missing.

Can you try to download the Visual C++ 2015 redistributable from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145. Please makes sure to download `vc_redist.x86.exe`, this is the 32-bit version which you will need.

As a side-node, you are correct that libimobiledevice-win32 ships as a zip file and does not use an installer. The idea is that the zip file contains all the files you need (although we obviously missed the `vcruntime140.dll` file.)